# Is there a way to return a directory's absolut path from a directory picker in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, directory, frontend

I'm working on an angular web project where i need the user to pick a local directory in his system where he wants certain files to be stored.
Due to security reasons this isnt allowed by navigators

The best result i came to is using `<input type="file" (change)="onDirectorySelected($event)" webkitdirectory/>` , but this only returns the relative path , and returns nothing if the directory is empty.
is there a workaround this or maybe a different approach?

Comment: What do you want to do with this path ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler as mentionned , the user chooses a directory where he wants to save certain files that he will later download , so i want to get that path to set it to the download files functions

Comment: You won't be able to do that. You can't pass a destination to download.

Comment: You have a absolutely no control or visibility over user filesystem (as you said, due to security reasons)